# How to mitigate noise from DC-DC converter used for reverse biasing diode?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, noise, switching

I am using the Q01-12 DC-DC [[datasheet](https://www.xppower.com/portals/0/pdfs/SF_Q_Series.pdf)] converter from XP power to reverse bias a photo diode; reverse biasing photo diodes turn them into ionizing radiation detectors.

I've designed a PCB that includes a charge-sensitive preamp, and a few stages of gain and signal shaping. The schematic is below.

[image: schematic]

Everything seems to be working rather well, but I've noticed some oscillatory noise in the signal. Here is an oscope shot of a detection event showing the gaussian shaped pulse is surrounded by a sine wave of frequency ~120 kHz. :

[image: event]
[image: noise]

I figured this was due to the DC-DC converter. According to the datasheet, the switching frequency ranges from 75 to 500 kHz.

[image: datasheet]

I've tried shielding the converter with copper tape, but this has had no effect on the noise. The scope shots are actually with the shielding applied. How can I mitigate this noise?

Comment: It's hard to tell at this zoom level, but it looks like your circuit can be cut about in half or more, with subsequent savings in power consumption and noise figure.  As for ripple, maybe LC filters to converter input and output are required.

Comment: You could have switching noise on your grounds. We need to see the layout to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Your scope might be picking up inductive pulses from the regulator, especially in its ground lead. Try moving your probe away from the regulator, even to the opposite side of the board.

You can further reduce noise to the load by adding a linear regulator after the DC-DC (that is, post-regulation).